# Python, CSV archive: inputing a column multiple rows as variables

Tags: python

This "Codes" column line is a piece of a CSV archive that have 12 columns and 5800 rows.

I need to compare all the rows in this specific column and return all the rows that have coincided.
There is a way to do that?

Codes: ['ARAMDS0001', 'ARAMDS0002', 'ARAMDS0003', 'ARAMDS0004', 'ARAMDS0005', 'ARAMDS0006', 'ARAMDS0007', 'ARAMDS0003', 'ARAMDS0007']

Comment: You need to compare them *to what*?

Comment: What exactly should be the result in this example, and why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

that is perfectly possible - You just create a hash for each list, and if the hash is the same, the list coincids with another entry.

You need to decide if :

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

since Lists are not hashable objects in python, You need to create Your own hash function, like:

```
n_hash = hash(''.join(sorted(['c', 'b', 'a'])))
```

then You add those hashes to a set - and if the hash code does exist already, You found a list which coincids.

if You have enough memory You might use the joined text, instead of calculating a hash :

```
my_rows = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a']]
my_set = set()
for actual_row in my_rows:
    s_hash = ''.join(sorted(actual_row))
    if s_hash in my_set:
        print(f'duplicate row: {actual_row}')
    else:
        my_set.add(s_hash)
```